# What happens with Tali if you chose not to continue the relationship in ME3

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-series

Back when I was playing ME1 I chose Liara. Then in ME2 I went with Tali. And then in ME3 when Tali shows up I chose to continue the relationship. However I've always wondered... What are the consequences of not continuing the relationship when you meet her in ME3? I know you can get back with Liara. but I'm more intrigued about what happens on Tali's side. I've looked around and it appears that from Liara's side she just shrug it off when she gives you the "I need to know where you stand" line. But what happens with Tali? Does she get angry? Is there anything about they that is worth mentioning given those conditions?

In regards to when you meet Tali the wiki says.

> After a brief discussion with the admirals, Tali and Shepard walk into another area of the ship where Shepard can inquire about their relationship. Tali informs Shepard that she can't discuss it in front of the Admirals and suggests that he invite her to his quarters for a more private conversation. If she has been invited to Shepard's quarters, Shepard may choose to continue the relationship with her.

But that's it. I do believe that Liara's question comes before Tali even appears at all. So considering you told Liara you wanted to get back, what happens with Tali if, during the quarian diplomacy conversation, you chose not to continue the relationship with her?

P.S. This is not considering the Shadow Broker DLC for ME2, I know there's some stuff about Liara there, but I never bought it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tali gets over it, and if Shepard romances neither Garrus nor Tali in Mass Effect 3, (and they're both alive), they hook up together.

Answer (score 0):

In general, *Mass Effect 3* handles jealousy more subtly than previous games:

- Most characters who you've previously romanced will ask you if you want to continue the relationship.  Refusing or ignoring this invitation will generally result in the character being disappointed but understanding.  With [one significant exception](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Priority:_Horizon#Confront_Henry_Lawson), refusing to continue a relationship has no effect on the plot.
- There are no "break-up" or "challenge" scenes as in the first two games.  Once you've progressed a given character's romantic arc beyond a certain point, all other romantic relationships automatically terminate.  At that point, it is not possible to dump your current partner.  These "lock-in" points are usually fairly obvious.
- Exes will sometimes acknowledge your new relationship in dialog, and may be annoyed with you or with your new (or old) partner, but these scenes are generally short and not too dramatic.

  - Liara in particular is quite unhappy if you lie to her about wanting to continue her relationship.  But she also indicates that she doesn't want to talk about it, and there's no further dialog available.
  - Bringing both Tali and Liara on a certain quest in the Rannoch arc can trigger some interesting dialog if you've dumped either of them in favor of the other.